# Getting GIT repository updated from server conent

Tags: git, web-deployment

I have a LOCAL >> GIT >> Server setup to develop websites and push them to server (on most cases I use dploy.io to push to server)

Once I deploy to production environment, clients run their site, make updates, upload files, etc etc.

At a given time a client might ask me to run x update to their site. But my local copy and git contains the site I deployed before they ran it and updated it.

My question then is, is there any way to update my git repository from the production server and then pull those changes to my local install? or that is something I should do manually (download the files, database, etc and replace my local files).

> EDIT
>   Due to some doubts, I clarify:  What I want to know is what commands
>   should I run on the server and where on it I should do in order to
>   update the repository with it's files. Also how should I do (if even
>   possible) when server doesn't offer SSH (I'm using dploy.io as I
>   mentioned when server doesn't have SSH).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stage files:

git add .

To commit changes:

git commit -m "Your Commit Message"

To add a remote:

git remote add remoteName remoteURL

Pushing changes to the remote:

git push remoteName

Pulling changes from the remote:

git pull remoteName

Answer (score 0):

You can tell your clients to push all the updates from the server to the repository located on github or bitbucket.

And you can just pull that repository to your local machine and perform any updates necessary and push the updates again. Now your clients can pull the updates.

Comment: Hi @Rohan thanks for your answer. I have access to the servers. What I don't know how to do is how to actually push the updates from the server to my git repo.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are getting at. Issuing the command git push from your server, after commiting the changes will update the repository. What else is the problem?

Comment: I know how to push my changes to git repository from my local install, but I don't know how to update the repository with server files, I don't know what commands, where should I run them (I suppose through SSH), etc to be able to update the repo from the server. Also I'm hosting on flywheel and they don't offer SSH that's why I use dploy.io to deploy to production.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to issue commands via SSH. That is how I do it with my aws hosting. Anyway, if your hosting provider does not have ssh, how are your clients making updates? I guess via SFTP? If this is the case, you probably have to download the updated application via SFTP too. And make the required changes. Although I would recommend that you shift your hosting solutions to somewhere you can get SSH. Life would be easier. I would also recommend that you try a Linux OS such as Ubuntu and use git via the CLI instead of the GUI. It comes handy.

Comment: Yes I know, I host on Flywheel (it's very good for wordpress managed). In case I have SSH (I do on others), what commands should I run? Would commands be the same than the ones I use locally? Would you mind to explain me these on a new answer so I can mark it as accepted answer? Best and thank you very much.